# Unable to modify Webform field type in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

We are working on Drupal 7 and we need to modify the "webform field type" of an existing webform. But we are unable to do that. We have also tried by deleting the existing field "form key" and tried creating a new field with the same "form key" but the data of the existing column gets deleted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but If you mean you want to change an existing field from existing webform, you can't do that. You can't do that with any Drupal field, once you created a field. You need to create a new field and migrate the data of the old field (using migrate api or script database) .

Comment: Thanks, @Daniela can you please give a brief detail or code as for how to migrate the data of the old field to the newly created field column?

Answer (score 0):

@Ravi, you can use the following module to migrate data from the old field to the new field, you just need to map the fields. The module contains an example:

https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d

If the previous option is too complicated, you can do the following trick:

export the old field table as INSERT format from the database, the table name will looks like this:

field_data_field_name

Then, just replace the name table from the old field to the new field table.

Finally, just execute those insert into your database.

This is an example, how an insert statement looks from a drupal field

```
INSERT INTO field_data_field_name(entity_type,bundle,deleted,entity_id,revision_id,`language`,delta,field_address_type_value,field_address_type_format) VALUES 
('entityform','solicitud_facturacion',0,656,656,'und',0,'AVENIDA',NULL);
```

I hope you understand this!